# Can I compile and run a linux app C++ source on Windows?

Tags: linux, cygwin

I have source code for a linux application. It seems I can compile it on windows with CygWin. My question is, after compilation, can I run it on Windows?

Comment: So, you've successfully compiled it on Windows with CygWin... but haven't tried running it?

Comment: No, I am still downloading the CygWin. I just want to make sure I am heading to the right direction.

Comment: @smwikipedia Ok, just curious.

Comment: Thanks, then I will keep trying. btw, what I try to run is this: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chongw/slda/readme.txt

Comment: Why does your question say `"a linux app"` - who said it was specifically for Linux?

Comment: I actually recommend you to install Linux on your laptop. Linux is a very friendly system for free software and scientific computing.

Comment: @Basile Totally agree, I will definitely use it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends totally on what APIs you use. If you stick to [C standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) things, like `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, etc. then yes, you can just compile and run on either OS.  Or for C++ apps, there is the [Standard C++ Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_standard_library), which any OS / development environment should provide.

If you use any OS-specific APIs, then of course it will not be compatible with another OS. There are libraries however, like [*APR*](https://apr.apache.org/) that try to abstract out the OS-specific bits.

From a casual glance at the [code you've linked to](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chongw/slda/), it appears to not use any OS-specific APIs. However:

> Note that this code requires the Gnu Scientific Library, http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

you'll need to get that library installed as well.

Comment: Thanks. It compiles and runs well on Windows. CygWin rocks!

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes; if you can compile a Linux application with Cygwin, then the compiled application will run on windows. Cygwin provides windows implementations of many unix system functions and libraries.

Comment: I didn't realize cygwin supported fork until reading this answer and looking into it. I must say, the way they emulate it on Windows is quite impressive!

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin/mingw(http://www.mingw.org/) should have most of the tools you need to build the binary. Once the build succeeds, you can run the binary (only) on windows.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You need Cygwin *or*  mingw, not both. They are alternatives.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Good point. Updated the answer accordingly.